# Python pandas convert (yy/mm) date format and select certain time range

Tags: python-2.7, date, pandas

guru, i am reading a big table with a column "issue_day" in "yy-mm" format. For example:

```
 status    issue_day
 active    11-Dec
 inactive  10-Dec
 active    9-Dec
 active    8-Jun
```

Is there any pythonic/pandas way to select data earlier than 2011? (For example, we only want data in 10-Dec & 09-Dec in this case).  There is only "dayfirst" in the pandas to_csv command, but I don't see "yearfirst".  Could any guru enlighten?  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
df=pd.DataFrame(['11-Dec','10-Dec','09-Dec'],columns=['issue_day'])
df['issue_day']=pd.to_datetime(df['issue_day'],format="%y-%b")
print df[df['issue_day']<'2011']
```

Comment: Thanks! But I encounter an error: "ValueError: time data '9-Dec' does not match format '%y-%b' (match)".  Any comment?

Comment: Can you post how to create the data frame?

Comment: Sure.  It is a big csv, so I do "df=pd.read_csv("data.csv")".  df['issue_day'] is one of the columns.

Comment: A better input can really help. I am not sure what the issue is otherwise

Comment: I know the issue.  "ValueError: time data '9-Dec' does not match format '%y-%b' (match)".  It is because the time data is '9-Dec' instead of '09-Dec'.  Any solution?

Comment: In your example you had 09. This is the reason why I ask you to post data. Try doing df['issue_date']=pd.to_datetime(df['issue_date'])

Comment: Another error message pops out: OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-12-11 00:00:00 in both test cases and the real file